# Please never remove clickable items in narrow displays

Tags: discussion, status-completed, user-experience, design

In light of this question on Stack Exchange [Deprecating our mobile views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views), the seems to be some ongoing effort to update some of the views of the website, that didn't display optimally on mobile.

But instead of focusing on things that are actually broken on mobile (hint: user profile page), there seem to be changes that do nothing but **diminish** the user experience on mobile (and also half screen).

The example that caught my attention was the removal of the "[Tools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools)" (10K only) link on dropdown of the review icon when the window is half width (and on mobile). See screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The whole point of using the "Full site" option all this time was to be able to access the **full** functionality of the website. If the direction is to start removing stuff from the "full site" view until it is identical to old "mobile" view, then what is the point of all the effort?

Therefore my request is for the upgrade process to strictly follow, under all circumstances, the following rule:

- **Anything that is clickable on the full width website, should always remain visible and clickable under ALL screen window widths, down to the minimum supported screen size** To achieve this, things that are stacked horizontally, should either get stacked vertically, or be made scrollable.

Comment: regarding user profile page, don't know if you are aware but they indeed [are working on it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368285/165773) :)

Comment: Already reported on MSE (which makes sense, since this is not specific to Stack Overflow): [The responsive mobile site's top-bar dropdowns are missing related links in each one's header](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/368708/289905).

Comment: @gnat: [For me at least it still looks terrible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fezsql.png). Without zooming it is impossible to see anything.

Comment: The tag [meta-tag:mobile] is redundant and can be confused with [meta-tag:mobile-web] which refers to the deprecated mobile version of Stack Exchange; simply [meta-tag:responsive-design] is enough and more accurate (i.e. small viewport does not imply mobile). Why does [meta-tag:unreachable-content-on-mobile] need to be a tag? Simply tag [meta-tag:bug] [meta-tag:design] [meta-tag:responsive-design].

Comment: @user000001 They are working on it, i.e. they aren’t finished. They’re currently working on the Profile, not the Activity page.

Comment: looks the same to me in portrait mode - agree it's quite poor. I use landscape instead (though still have to zoom sometimes - and of course with tons of vertical scrolling) - have you tried it?

Comment: @SebastianSimon: I agree they are related, but not exact duplicates. Here I propose a general rule to prohibit any functionality from being removed from the page in narrow windows. It's not just about the specific link.

Comment: @uder00001 mobile sadly identifies wide range of devices which can have 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 or 43" inch screen.. just because the OS or browser type doesn't identify what client actually is as a hardware. It can be a NUC PC, web-notebook, kiosk, singleboard monoblock computer, smart-TV (and there are 40 or 63" inch ones, 4K resolution), tablet PC up to 20", yes, there are 20", but more common at 8" which are quite enough for desktop version. All those get identified as "mobile platform" by web backend.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie: You are correct, but the whole point of the "responsive design" paradigm is to achieve the same user experience regardless of the client that is being used. For narrow screens, stacking, modals, and overflow can be used, but  removing essential functionality is not acceptable.

Comment: @yivi: I won't contest the retagging of the question, but the emphasis on the word "NEVER" was intentional to highlight the rigidity of the proposed rule.

Comment: Titles do not render makdown, and should not include extra formatting or extraneous symbols. Save the emphasis for the question body proper. Titles should be read in the list naturally, not try to draw attention with unnecessary formatting.

Comment: @yivi: Ok, that's your opinion, but IMO is doesn't give you the right to start rollback wars on other people's questions. Anyway you win, I'm not into the rollback war game, cheers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You’re totally right that those links shouldn’t go away at smaller viewport widths.

Before deprecating the mobile views for these panels, most of them didn’t show any links in the first row (but they did have an `X` close button). We’ve been trying to keep the mobile layout views as close to what they were initially, but went broad and hid those first row links in all small viewports.

All this is to say: thank you for bringing this up and sorry for the annoyance. We have a fix on the way that will show those first two links in all contexts (small and large, mobile and non-mobile). It’ll also ensure that the `X` close button is shown on small viewports.

> Anything that is clickable on the full width website, should always remain visible and clickable under ALL screen window widths, down to the minimum supported screen size

There are some affordances that will violate your rule (the previously mentioned panel close button for instance), but I generally agree with this.

Comment: Good to hear that this is getting addressed! When this is fixed, would you mind updating [my bug report on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368708/622284) as well?

Comment: Absolutely! I was just about to respond to your post there.